# How to find sniff communication to smart card reader?

Tags: smartcard, sniffing, rfid

I use a smart card reader and I want to know if the reader is secure. How to sniff communication between card and card reader?

Comment: Are you using a reader/writer where the card is put in?

Comment: I think you want to capture and analyse the packets sent to host from a peripheral using a ***protocol analyser device***. you will have to plug a interception hardware between both devices and configure the company-dependant software to use the hardware. It's no more than that.

Comment: I want to capture communication between smart card reader and smart card

Comment: Ah I'm almost there, there is a software tool that can do this https://github.com/crocs-muni/APDUPlay This tool takes "control" over the reader' driver communication with the card that is inbuilt in the reader itself (driver). It makes logging of PC/SC communication possible.

Comment: Can you tell us whether it worked?